# absolutely positioned element in a button problem

Tags: css, firefox

have a wierd issue. for the life of me can't trace this back (its gonna be a noob prob I am sure - just can't see it!)

I have a  relatively positioned and a span within that is absolutely position right:0 top: 0 bottom: 0 and has a width of 20px....

fine in chrome/safari ie9 (not checked 7/8 yet) but firefox is setting right: -6px botom -3px...

Pretty stumped - i've been looking for a while and the trees are getting in the way of the woods...

here's the page - and its the button on the search form in left hand panel.

[demo page](http://css.abacusmedia.co.uk)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a quick play with firebug on it, and found that

.panel button {height: 1.5em} (public-layout.css, line 102)

and button {font-size: 0.9em} (public-tipography.css, line 60)

Change the layout in some way.

Comment: Thanks Dave. the line height takes care of the change in top offset but alas not the right offset.  This is quite strange behaviour for firefox - other browsers appear to behave as expected!

Answer (score 0):

```
button span {
bottom:0;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
width:20px;
}
```